# Allow organisations to edit profile

Tags: profile, permissions, access

My organisation is an umbrella group for a number of organisations around the world. We're wanting to use CiviCRM to administer a network of organisations, alongside our own individual supporters.

I want to be able to send a periodic checksum email to representatives from the organisations who make up our network, to make sure the various details we hold on them are correct. I've set up the profile but when I try to access a test organisation via a Checksum email I get the message " This profile is configured for contact type 'Member_organisation'. It cannot be used to edit contacts of other types."

Does anyone have any guidance on how we can achieve this? Ideally the person editing the profile won't have to have their own record on our CiviCRM database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I worked out the problem - I needed to change the permissions in Drupal to allow access to profiles. When I send a test organisation a test email to my own account, I can access the profile with the current data we hold viewable and editable.